# Django Post detail url url not found

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Django Post list/detail urls, `domain.com/api/v1/1` and `domain.com/api/v1` not found given the following url patterns, note that pk with value of 1 exists,

Project urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
  
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1/', include('posts.urls'))
]
```

Api urls

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import PostList, PostDetail

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/', PostDetail.as_view()),
    path('', PostList.as_view()),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a slash to the end of `api/v1`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
  
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1/', include('posts.urls'))
]
```